# Reference files from dynamic object

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am working on a [Gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile), and am having difficulty getting a copy task to work the way I want.

I have an [Uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) task defined using a [dynamic file object](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) like:

```
uglify: {
  files: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src',
    src: [
      'some/path/file1.js',
      'another/path/file2.js'
    ],
    dest: 'dst',
    ext: '.min.js'
  }
}
```

This task works great, and I get my files written out as 'dst/some/path/file1.min.js' and 'dst/another/path/file2.min.js'.

I am working on a [copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) task, where I would like to copy the files I just built somewhere else.  Rather than redefining the rule, I would like to reference the file set with a template.

If I use

```
copy: {
  deploy: {
    src: '<%= uglify.files %>',
    dest: 'deploy/'
  }
}
```

then I get the

> Warning: Object # has no method 'indexOf'

error.

For various reasons beyond the scope of this question, globbing tricks won't work for the deploy.

So, in a copy task, how can I reference the set of files that another task just created?

Comment: [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) useminPrepare task generates configurations for copy, uglify, etc.  Depending upon how important this is and how much work you are willing to do, you could look at that project for some ideas.

Comment: Not trying to be spammy, but this also looked interesting: http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/using-grunts-config-api/

Answer (score 1):

You have `files: {}` as an object. It should be an array `files: []`.

```
uglify: {
  files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src',
    src: [
      'some/path/file1.js',
      'another/path/file2.js'
    ],
    dest: 'dst',
    ext: '.min.js'
  }]
}
```

Comment: correct the syntax error on line 3, object notation must be enclosed with {}

Comment: It seems to already be the same as you typed! and is syntax error free!  @Sawtaytoes

Answer (score 0):

The src on copy config expected to be string or array, but you set an object on it, and when grunt tries to apply indexof method on the src of copy task, error will be the result. you can avoid this by setting uglify.files as array of objects, like this:

```
uglify: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src',
        src: [
            'some/path/file1.js',
            'another/path/file2.js'
        ],
        dest: 'dst',
        ext: '.min.js'
   }]
}
```

Then, it will pass the error but you goal won't meet. you need to select dest of uglify as src for copy. the solution is the grunt method, TEMP FILES, you should set uglify dest in a temp path and then select what you need from there as src of copy task. something like this:

```
copy:{
    deploy:{
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'dst'
            src: '**/*.min.js'
            dest: 'deploy'
        }]
    }    
}
```